# Is there a way to disable the black notification bar for nonsense?

Tags: support

So, I'm all for an black bar when there's an important community notification/discussion etc... for big changes.

But nonsense like this, a podcast I'm not interested in, I can't be bothered with it and find it not worthy of a black bar notification. A simple highlight in the right column suffices.

[image: black bar with nonsense]

If this can't be stopped I'll simply block the notification element in uBlock, but I'd like to know if there's a setting to stop non policy changes/developer survey black bars.

Comment: Related post on MSE: [Can we reserve the top bar announcements for actual site news?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338766/294055)

Comment: My userscript [ReduceClutter](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ReduceClutter.user.js) removes the announcement bar if it contains the keyword "podcast"

Comment: I closed it with the (x) and it re-appeared multiple times after.